# Phpmyadmin Automatic Table Updater

Tags: mysql, events, phpmyadmin, task

Hi i have a task that must checked once a day.
I am using MySql database and can i add a task from phpmyadmin to do this task once a day.
There is a some options routines,triggers and events.I think one of them doing this but i couldnt find any documentation about it.
Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seel [19.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) and [13.1.12 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) for some documentation.